# Enable or disable login button in foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, zurb-foundation

I`m use front-end framework Foundation. How i can in this menu enable Log in button only if Login and Password input filled text.

```
<form data-abide="ajax">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Login" />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns text-center">
   <a href="#" class="button tiny disabled">Log in</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns text-center">
   <br /><a href="#" class="button tiny">Register</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns text-center">
   <br /><a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: To be precise.mention the exact problem being faced.Google is a good friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a function to watch the onkeypress listener for the input box. Here is a working fiddle of how to do it on the username and you could do something similar for the password input as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/fFLq4/

Add a couple element id's to your elements:

```
<form data-abide="ajax">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
   <input type="text" id="loginTxtBox" placeholder="Login" />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns text-center">
   <a href="#" id="loginButton" class="button tiny disabled">Log in</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns text-center">
   <br /><a href="#" class="button tiny">Register</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns text-center">
   <br /><a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

And add the javascript function to listen for the keypress:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("loginTxtBox");

textBox.onkeypress=function(textBox){
    if(this.value.length >= 5)
    {
        document.getElementById("loginButton").className = "button tiny";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("loginButton").className = "button tiny disabled";
    }
};
```

This will only activate your login button once you have at least 5 characters in it. Apply this to your password input as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you would like to show the login form only if the user clicks on the Login Link.

To achieve this, I would suggest moving the links outside the  and use any of these (toggle/show/slide) in jQuery to show it on click.

**Here is the modified HTML:**

```
<form id="loginForm" data-abide="ajax">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Login" />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
 </div>
</form>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns text-center">
   <a id="login" href="#" class="button tiny disabled">Log in</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns text-center">
   <br /><a href="#" class="button tiny">Register</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns text-center">
   <br /><a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**And here is a working fiddle of how to show/hide the login form:**

http://jsfiddle.net/9C4s7/

The commented line in the js toggles the slide (clicking the link will show the form, clicking it again will hide it). The active line will only make it slide down once clicked. So, you go ahead and choose whichever works best for you!

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. But i want... If login and password is empty then Log in button is disable. But if user write test in text inpyt then Log in button is active.